Vue 3. Arrastrar y soltar. No me deja seleccionar el texto de la página. (drag and drop)
La aplicación en Vue 3 funciona y al arrastrar los ficheros en la página web los recoge y los procesa... Pero no puedo selecionar ningún texto de la página web.
El componente principal:
App.vue
<template>
      <DisplayData />
      <DropArea @files-dropped="addFiles" />
      <ul>
            <li v-for="item in data.filesDropped">                  
                  {{ item.name }}
            </li>
      </ul>
</template>

<script setup>
import DropArea from './DropArea.vue';
import DisplayData from './DisplayData.vue';

import useFilesDropped from './files-dropped.js';
const { addFiles, data } = useFilesDropped();

</script>

El componente que se encarga de capturar la información de los ficheros arrastrados en toda la pantalla. Todo apunta a que aquí falla algo en la definición del código que hace que no permita seleccionar lo que está en el div inferior:
DropArea.vue
<template>
  <div class="area-drop" @drop="onDrop($event)" @dragover="onDragOver($event)" @dragenter="onDragEnter"
    @dragleave="onDragLeave" :class="{ 'drag-over': isDragging }">
    <h1 v-if="isDragging">Arrastra tus ficheros aquí</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const emit = defineEmits(['files-dropped'])

const isDragging = ref(false);
const onDragEnter = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  isDragging.value = true;
}
const onDragLeave = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  isDragging.value = false;
}

const onDrop = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  isDragging.value = false;
  emit('files-dropped', [...event.dataTransfer.files])
  // let files = event.dataTransfer.files;
};

const onDragOver = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
};
</script>


<style scoped>
.area-drop {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(46, 153, 189);
  border: 2px dashed black;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0;  
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.area-drop h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  pointer-events: none; /* Para que no parpadee el texto cuando se pasa el cursor por encima - Se puede eliminar y el problema pasa igual */
}

.drag-over {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
</style>

Componente que trata de mostrar la información. Si se arrastra ficheros de texto, muestra una lista dinámica de los nombres de los ficheros arrastrados. El texto Lorem Ipsum es para probar que no se puede seleccionar y copiar el texto que muestra la aplicación.
DisplayData.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <p><strong>Arrastrar aquí los ficheros de texto</strong></p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
  </div>
</template>

En el siguiente código, gestiona los archivos arrastrados a la aplicación y evita que haya duplicidades.
files-dropped.js
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue';

export default function () {

  const data = reactive({
    filesDropped: []
  })

  const files = ref([]);

  class UploadableFile {
    constructor(file) {
      this.id = `${file.name}-${file.size}-${file.lastModified}-${file.type}`
      this.name = file.name
      this.url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
      this.content = null
    }
  }

  const addFiles = (newFiles) => {

    let allContensFlat = [];

    newFiles.forEach((file) => {
      let candidateFile = new UploadableFile(file);
      let isFileExist = data.filesDropped.some(({ id }) => id === candidateFile.id)
      if (!isFileExist) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (file) => {
          candidateFile.content = file.target.result;
          data.filesDropped.push(candidateFile)
        };
        reader.readAsText(file, 'ISO-8859-1');
      } else {
        console.log("Fichero arrastrado antes" + candidateFile.id)
      }
    })
  };

  return { addFiles, data };
}

Código en Vue SFC Playground
Inspirado en ilovepdf punto com, deseo mostrar duplicados de unos ficheros csv. Es mi primera aplicación fuera de los tutoriales de vue.

Hola Mario, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que sepas como funciona la plataforma y de paso ganes tu primer medalla. Con respecto a tu problema, es de esperarse ya que el elemento con la clase area-drop está por arriba de todo y ocupa todo. Que no se vea, no significa que no esté.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! El codigo debe estar en la pregunta...

Tienes razón @Marcos , pero ¿como lo hace ilovepdf punto com? Cuando arrastras un PDF por ejemplo para unir PDF, puede seleccionar el texto de la página. Y en cambio sigue siendo posible arrastrar otro PDF en cualquier punto de la pantalla. ¿Como lo puedo conseguir?

Al implementar un "area-drop" el elemento que detecta el evento, por lo general, contiene la aplicación. En otras palabras, es un contenedor y dentro de este está "todo lo demás".
Ejemplo:
Aplicado a tu caso, podrías hacer las siguientes modificaciones:
App.vue
El componente DropArea contiene a DisplayData
<template>
  <DropArea @files-dropped="addFiles">
    <DisplayData />
  </DropArea>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in data.filesDropped">                  
      {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script setup>
import DropArea from './DropArea.vue';
import DisplayData from './DisplayData.vue';

import useFilesDropped from './files-dropped.js';
const { addFiles, data } = useFilesDropped();

</script>

DropArea.vue
Dentro de este componente realizamos las siguientes modificaciones:

Creamos un div "contenedor" donde suscribimos todos los eventos de drag

Creamos un div "layer" que será el "popup" a mostrar cuando se detecte que el drag ha comenzado.

Creamos un div donde:

Agregamos un <slot> para mostrar "los hijos" del componente
Suscribimos al evento onDragLeave, para evitar que se propague al div "contenedor"


Creamos una clase .hidden la cual utilizaremos para ocultar el "layer"


Teniendo todo lo anterior y en base a los eventos que se disparen, agregamos o quitamos al "layer" la clase hidden.
<template>
  <div @drop="onDrop($event)" @dragover="onDragOver($event)" @dragenter="onDragEnter" @dragleave="onDragLeave">
    <div ref="layer" class="area-drop hidden">
      <h1>Arrastra tus ficheros aquí</h1>
    </div>
    <div @dragleave="onSlotDragLeave">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const emit = defineEmits(['files-dropped'])

const layer = ref(null);

const onDragEnter = (event) => {
  layer.value.classList.remove('hidden');
  event.preventDefault();
}
const onDragLeave = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  layer.value.classList.add('hidden');
}

const onDrop = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  layer.value.classList.add('hidden');
  emit('files-dropped', [...event.dataTransfer.files])
  // let files = event.dataTransfer.files;
};

const onSlotDragLeave = (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
}

const onDragOver = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
};
</script>


<style scoped>
.area-drop {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(46, 153, 189);
  border: 2px dashed black;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.area-drop.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.area-drop h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  pointer-events: none;
}
</style>

Demo
